# My wireless (USB Dongle) headphones are not detected [ubuntu 20.04]

Tags: sound, headphones

My wireless headphones that use a USB dongle are not showed as audio devices in the settings
The system logs show them being connected, but I can't use them as there is no setting anywhere showing them.

The problem isn't I can't hear with them, it's that it's impossible for me to use them because the system doesn't let me chose them as an audio device.

Any possible solutions?

They are using a USB dongle that came in the box, nothing special.

Comment: Are these headphones Bluetooth-based or do they use an alternative technology? A make and model number might help someone provide a more specific solution 

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried alsamixer?

Open up Terminal, then type alsamixer and press Enter.

You will get an odd sort of panel with all your output and input devices listed across the bottom, and a vertical display of the sound levels.

Left and right arrows pan through the list of sound devices, and up and down arrows increase or decrease the sound levels.

When you're dome making adjustments, just press Esc (the escape key) to exit.

Also read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer

﻿

Answer (score -2):

I have succeeded with very much the same problem, my speakers not appearing in Sound settings. I've tried every option I have found, but a mix and match worked for me.

I went to https://techwiser.com/fix-bluetooth-device-doesnt-auto-connect-in-linux/ and followed the first two points, having tried all before, to ensure they were auto enabled and trusted.

1. Edit the file `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and add the line

   ```
   AutoEnable=true
   ```
2. Get the MAC address of the device from Bluetooth Settings and use `bluetoothctl` to trust the device with this command (replacing `XX...` with the actual MAC address:

   ```
   bluetoothctl trust XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
   ```

I then tried [Bluetooth speaker connected but not listed in sound output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824404/bluetooth-speaker-connected-but-not-listed-in-sound-output)

I followed the top answer, which I had followed before, but having auto enabled and trusted, it worked.

I'm no expert just thought it is worth a try, Good Luck Noah.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing to Ask Ubuntu! While these links may be useful, it [would be better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts in your answer and provide the links for reference. Your answer would have no use if the links would stop working for whatever reason. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Bluetooth.