# Bluetooth speakers say connected but will not work in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, blueman

I have a dual boot system with Ubuntu 20.04 & Windows 10.

My Bluetooth Steenssen speakers work on Windows automatically and used to work on Ubuntu. As soon as I reboot to Ubuntu the solid blue light flashes. I have tried all Ubuntu options listed that have appeared under many searches to no avail. When I try to Load Blueman it states that it is loaded by default and Pulseaudio is also installed.

Bluetooth is on and in Bluetooth manager the speakers show and give levels of signal strength. They do not have the Bluetooth symbol next to them.
In Settings, Bluetooth, they appear but say disconnected, I can click on them and connect them, but checking sound settings they never appear. On next inspection they are disconnected again.

One of the many attempts I found, started with `sudo vim` (I copied and pasted, so no typo) and it replied "command not found", just in case that is useful.

Answer (score 0):

I Have succeeded after some time trying a combination approach. I posted this in case any body else wishes to try my solution.

I went to https://techwiser.com/fix-bluetooth-device-doesnt-auto-connect-in-linux/ and followed the first two points, having tried all before, to ensure they were auto enabled and trusted.

I then tried [Bluetooth speaker connected but not listed in sound output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824404/bluetooth-speaker-connected-but-not-listed-in-sound-output)

I followed the top answer, which I had followed before, but having auto enabled and trusted, it worked.

Thank you so much!