My Bluetooth disconnects each time I boot up my laptop
My Ubuntu version is 22.04.4
Every time I use my laptop Bluetooth works fine, then very randomly it disconnects. I need to restart my laptop to turn it on. I can not use the toggle button to turn it on. It tells me I need a dongle.
How can i fix this?

Have you seen the first answer/reply from this link? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331009/bluetooth-on-ubuntu-20-04-constantly-disconnecting
