# All other bluetooth audio devices work except Nothing ear(1) tws on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluetooth-speaker, blueman

I am able to connect my TWS(Nothing ear 1) to Ubuntu but they are not detected as audio devices.
It works fine for all other speakers and bluetooth headphones.
What might be the issue?

Comment: same, tried every possible solution , it connects as unknown device

Comment: in my case, i just pair the <address> and trust the <devices> bluetooth name and rescan bluetoothctl. Probably you need check your sound settings.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1267910

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

*If you mean to increase your chances of solving the problem:*

1. *Consider using these suggestions as a guide, nos as a step-by-step instructions manual.*
2. *Take your time to read linked posts, tinker a bit, and post what you get.*
3. *Try reading the output messages and interpret what they tell you. Even web-search a bit. Especially with warnings and errors, e.g. `Oct 07 22:19:28 ank-pc bluetoothd[535134]: 67:1D:94:89:D7:C4: error updating services: Host is down (112)` after `systemctl status bluetooth`, or `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.ConnectionAttemptFailed`.*

*I trust the time it takes will be far more economic than relying on out-of-the-box solutions.*

Please reboot, connect the device again, try these commands and post output

```
$ pactl list | grep -nH -A 5 -B 5 blue
$ pactl list modules short
$ dpkg -l | grep pulseaudio-module
```

followed by solution 2 below.

Note that the solutions suggested probably require rebooting and connecting the device again, prior to trying them out, so you have your system in a "fresh" state.

Possibly related:

1. [PulseAudio can not load bluetooth module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module)
2. https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/How-to-fix-bluetooth-speakers-on-ubuntu.html
3. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/595864/cannot-pair-connect-to-my-headphones-failure-module-initialization-failed
4. https://forums.debian.net//viewtopic.php?f=7&t=124230

---

You could try a few solutions (you may need to install a package if you don't have the required program):

1. (a) Unpair the device, (b) run in a terminal: `$ sudo pkill pulseaudio`, (c) pair again the earphone ([credit](https://askubuntu.com/a/846107/226614); see other answers there!).
2. (a) `pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover`, (b) `pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover`.
3. (a) `sudo rmmod btusb`, (b) `sudo modprobe btusb`.
4. (a) `bluetoothctl`, (b) `scan on`, (c) `pair <address>`, (d) `connect <address>`, (e) `trust <address>`.
5. Use `pavucontrol`. Since it is a GUI, you should tinker a bit with its options. In particular, *Output Devices* and *Configuration*.
6. [a2db.py](https://gist.github.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae). Install with `curl "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pylover/d68be364adac5f946887b85e6ed6e7ae/raw/install.sh" | sh`.
7. `pulseaudio -k`.
8. `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth`.
9. More radical: replace pulseaudio with pipewire, see [this](https://kumarvinay.com/how-to-enable-bluetooth-headset-microphone-support-in-ubuntu-20-04/) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1333404/how-to-replace-pulseaudio-with-pipewire-on-ubuntu-21-04).

If none of this helps, a diagnosis is needed.
Please post the output of a few commands, with the earphones connected.

```
$ uname -a
$ apt list --installed bluetooth* blueman* bluez*
$ lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 -i 'Net'
$ lspci -nnk | grep -n -A 4 -i 'Audio'
$ lsusb
$ rfkill list
$ bluetoothctl list
$ bluetoothctl show
$ bluetoothctl devices
$ bluetoothctl info <address>
$ hciconfig -a
$ zgrep -i blue /var/log/dmesg.*
$ zgrep -i blue /var/log/syslog.*
$ systemctl status bluetooth
$ inxi -F
$ aplay -l
$ sudo lshw -C multimedia
$ dpkg -l | grep alsa
$ cat /etc/pulse/default.pa
$ lsmod | grep bt
$ journalctl --no-pager | grep -i -n blue | head -4000
$ systemctl | grep -i blue
$ pacmd list-cards
```

Also, what options you get in
*Settings* -> *Sound* -> *Output* -> *Output Device*.

**Notes**:

1. You may have to install `inxi`.
2. `<address>` is something like `XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX`, obtained for the earphones from `bluetoothctl devices`.
3. Avoid "narrating" what you obtained; copy+paste the output.
4. Include from copy+paste also the exact command you entered.
5. If the output of one specific command is very long to post, use pastebin. Please do not use pastebin to dump everything together, make for an easier reading of those who try to help.

Comment: Please find the requested info at https://pastebin.com/8rFMyDi0

Comment: @AnkushK - Right post. While I look at it:
1) Please note that I have added 4 commands to the disgnostics.
2) Please try a few of the tentative solutions (1-4, 7, 8 are harmless to try) and post the outcome.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/7CYNnByq. I tried above commands. I have moved to pipewire. Added output of `pactl info` and bluetooth status. I have JBL Go 3. It is able to connect over A2DP. Do you think it is issue with Nothing earphones(They work fine on windows and mobile)?

Answer (score 1):

navigate to your terminal and run the below command

> `$ sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

It worked for my Nothing ear(2) and I hope that works for you as well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

finally Solved, you have to enter paring mode  by opening case and long pressing the round button on the case. then you will find two nothing ear in the devices list, try to connect to one of them, if it does not work, try other it should work.